# Dots persist on D3 graph for angularjs

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am using NVD3 for my graphs and I have this issue where the dots that show up on hover will start to persist as you over over the line. Does anyone have any idea on how to make sure these disappear when the move moves away from them?

Here is the component:

```
;(function() {
  angular.module('canopy.common.components.largeStandardChart')
    .component('largeStandardChart', {
      templateUrl: 'app/common/components/chart-components/large-standard-chart/large-standard-chart.html',
      controller: LargeStandardChartController,
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      bindings: {
        kpi: "<",
        updateGraph: '=',
        frequency: '<'
      }
    });

  LargeStandardChartController.$inject = ['$rootScope', 'BanyanUtilsService', 'ConfigurationService', '$timeout'];
  function LargeStandardChartController($rootScope, UtilsService, CS, $timeout) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.kpiTrend = [];
    vm.kpiTargetTrend = [];
    vm.kpiProjectedTrend = [];
    vm.predictedDate = null;

    var allTrends = vm.kpi.trend.length && vm.kpi.trend[0].values.length ? vm.kpi.trend[0].values : [];

    vm.chart = {
      chartOptions: {
        chart: {
          type: 'lineChart',
          height: 250,
          area: CS.getOrgConfig().graph.general.fillArea,
          margin : {
            top: 15,
            right: 40,
            bottom: 50,
            left: 70
          },
          x: (function(d) { return d.time }),
          y: (function(d) { return d.value }),
          clipVoronoi: false,
          xAxis: {
            showMaxMin: false,
            staggerLabels: vm.frequency === 'DAY' ? false : true,
            tickFormat: function(d) {
              return vm.frequency === 'DAY'
                ? d3.time.format(CS.getOrgConfig().dateTime.d3DateFormat)(new Date(d))
                : d3.time.format(CS.getOrgConfig().dateTime.d3DateTimeFormat)(new Date(d));
            }
          },
          yAxis: {
            showMaxMin: true,
            tickFormat: function (d) {
              return vm.kpi.kpiMeasure === 'NUMBER' && d ? d.toFixed(1) : UtilsService.getFormattedData(d, vm.kpi.kpiMeasure);
            }
          },
          tooltip: {
            hideDelay: 0
          },
          showXAxis: CS.getOrgConfig().graph.xAxis.showXAxis,
          showYAxis: CS.getOrgConfig().graph.yAxis.showYAxis,
          showLegend: false,
          transitionDuration: 350,
          useInteractiveGuideline: false
        }
      }
    };

    vm.$onInit = function() {
      if(vm.updateGraph) { vm.updateGraph.handler = vm.updateGraphData; }
      if (!vm.kpi) { vm.kpi = { trend: vm.kpiTrend, kpiMeasure: "PERCENTAGE" } }
      setTrends();

      d3.select(window).on('mouseout', function () {
        d3.selectAll('.nvtooltip').style('opacity', '0');
      });
    };

    function setTrends() {
      _.set(vm.chart, 'chartData', []);
      vm.kpiTrend = [];
      vm.kpiProjectedTrend = [];

      _.forEach(allTrends, function(kpi) {
        if (_.has(kpi, 'predict')) {
          vm.kpiProjectedTrend.push(kpi);
        } else {
          if (CS.getOrgConfig().graph.general.showNullValues) {
            vm.kpiTrend.push(kpi);
          } else {
            if (kpi.value) { vm.kpiTrend.push(kpi) }
          }
        }
      });

      if (!vm.kpi.hideTarget && !vm.kpiProjectedTrend.length) {
        vm.chart.chartData.push({
          key: CS.getOrgConfig().labels.target.single,
          classed: "dashed",
          color: $rootScope.branding.canopyBrandColor,
          seriesIndex: 2,
          strokeWidth: 1,
          values: getTargetValues()
        });
      }

      if (vm.kpiTrend.length) {
        vm.chart.chartData.push({
          key: 'Value',
          classed: "solid",
          area: CS.getOrgConfig().graph.general.fillArea,
          color: $rootScope.branding.canopyBrandColor,
          seriesIndex: 0,
          strokeWidth: 2,
          values: vm.kpiTrend
        });
      }

      if (vm.kpiProjectedTrend.length) {
        vm.chart.chartOptions.chart.useInteractiveGuideline = false;

        var lastCurrentValue = angular.copy(vm.kpiTrend).pop();
        var firstPredictedValue = angular.copy(vm.kpiTrend).pop();
        vm.kpiProjectedTrend.unshift(firstPredictedValue);

        vm.endDate = moment.unix(allTrends[ allTrends.length - 1 ].time / 1000).format(CS.getOrgConfig().dateTime.dateFormat); // Divide by 1000 for miliseconds coming from server

        vm.chart.chartData.push({
          key:'Projected',
          classed: "dashed",
          color: $rootScope.branding.canopyBrandColor,
          strokeWidth: 1,
          seriesIndex: 3,
          values: vm.kpiProjectedTrend
        });

        var top = 0, bottom = 0;

        if (allTrends.length) {
          var top = _.maxBy(allTrends, function(tr) { return tr.value }).value;
          var bottom = _.minBy(allTrends, function(tr) { return tr.value }).value;
        }

        var yTop = vm.kpi.kpiMeasure === 'PERCENTAGE' ? 103 : top + ((top - bottom) * 0.07);
        var yBottom = vm.kpi.kpiMeasure === 'PERCENTAGE' ? 0 : bottom - ((top - bottom) * 0.04);

        vm.chart.chartData.push({
          classed: "solid",
          strokeWidth: 1,
          seriesIndex: 4,
          values: [
            {time: lastCurrentValue.time, value: yTop},
            {time: lastCurrentValue.time, value: yBottom},
          ],
          color: '#ff0005'
        });
      }

      setDomain();
    }

    function setDomain () {
      var top = 0, bottom = 0;

      if (allTrends.length) {
        top = _.maxBy(allTrends, function(tr) { return tr.value }).value;
        bottom = _.minBy(allTrends, function(tr) { return tr.value }).value;
      }

      bottom = bottom < 1 && bottom > 0 ? 0 : bottom;
      if (top === bottom) { bottom = top - bottom; }
      if (top + bottom === 0) { top = 1; }

      var yTop = vm.kpi.kpiMeasure === 'PERCENTAGE' ? 103 : top + ((top - bottom) * 0.05);
      var yBottom = vm.kpi.kpiMeasure === 'PERCENTAGE' ? 0 : bottom - ((top - bottom) * 0.05);
      vm.chart.chartOptions.chart.yDomain = [yBottom, yTop];
    }

    vm.updateGraphData = function(trend) {
      allTrends = trend.length && trend[0].values.length ? trend[0].values : [];
      setTrends();
      vm.api.updateWithOptions(vm.chart.chartOptions);
      vm.api.updateWithData(trend);
      vm.api.refresh();
    };

    function getTargetValues() {
      var trend = angular.copy(allTrends);
      _.forEach(trend, function(t) {
        t.value = vm.kpi.targetValue;
      });
      return trend;
    }
  }
})();
```

and here is what it looks like when I hover:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having this issue I have finally found the solution. I had to add a listener on the mouseout event and remove the `hover` class that is added to the `.nv-point` which is the dot. It looks like this:

```
d3.select(window).on('mouseout', function () {
  d3.selectAll('.nv-point').classed('hover', false);
});
```